# Show div when DOM is fully loaded in IE, using JQuery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, onload

I need to show a DIV containing a slideshow only when the DOM is fully loaded.

I used this script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        new Image("images/layout/wallpaper.jpg");
        new Image("images/layout/plates.png");

        $('#slideshow').css('display', 'block');
        $('#slideshow').nivoSlider({
            effect: 'fade',
            animSpeed: 500,
            pauseTime: 3000,
            directionNav: false,
            directionNavHide: false,
            controlNav: false,
            keyboardNav: false,
            pauseOnHover: false
        });
    });
    </script>
```

The #slideshow DIV is defined as display: hidden. In Internet Explorer the DIV never shows.
How can I solve this?

====================================

Edited to:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(window).load(function() {
            new Image("images/layout/wallpaper.jpg");
            new Image("images/layout/plates.png");

            $('#slideshow').nivoSlider({
                effect: 'fade',
                animSpeed: 500,
                pauseTime: 3000,
                directionNav: false,
                directionNavHide: false,
                controlNav: false,
                keyboardNav: false,
                pauseOnHover: false
            });
            $('#slideshow').css('display', 'block');
        });
    });
```

Still no difference.
This is the CSS for the #slideshow DIV:

```
#slideshow {
    z-index: 0;

   height: 457px;
   width: 660px;
   position: relative;
}
```

The "display: none;" property is defined as inline.

Comment: Can you share CSS and HTML code...

Comment: Might be an obvious, but just checking: Does the slideshow show correctly when you have it `display: block` from the start? And further, could you put in some log trace or alert after you init the slideshow, just to see if that really triggers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may well be this simple :

```
$('#slideshow').show()
```

Also, any reason you're using document.load event and not:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
```

Answer (score 1):

Try wait for the dom to be ready, like:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
... your code inside the window load function ...
});
```

Comment: The load event is fired after th ready one. @user1119017 may well have a reason for waiting for this to fire.

Comment: Still no difference. IE just doesn't care and seems to ignore the css() instruction. Same with show().

Comment: Point taken - still certain practices are frequently used for a reason, just thought the OP could give it a shot.

Comment: OK. Sorry. I obviously have no knowledge at all about browser events. I was trying to handle the window.load event WITHIN the document.ready event. By keeping the sole document.ready everything behaves as expected.

Comment: you're welcome. that's what I actually meant, but maybe I should have just posted the whole code in the correct form... as a rule of thumb, encapsulate your jquery in a document ready function. welcome to SO :)